# WARNING: GLFW: Failed to initialize Window

Tags: glfw, raylib

I am so green with C++ i look like the hulk......
Here is the full code, i'm following a coder from Youtube

```
     #include <raylib.h>
     using namespace std;


     int main()
    {
InitWindow(300, 600, "raylib Tetris");
SetTargetFPS(60);
while (WindowShouldClose() == false)
{
    BeginDrawing();

    
    EndDrawing();

}









 Full error.....

 WARNING: GLFW: Error: 65543 Description: WGL: 
 OpenGL profile requested but WGL_ARB_create_context_profile is unavailable

 WARNING: GLFW: Failed to initialize Window
```

L:\VisualStudio\ProjectTestCode\x64\Debug\ProjectTestCode.exe
(process 26016) exited with code -1073741819.